# VS2010 and CruiseControl.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

We are using CruiseControl.net 1.5.0.6237 with VS2008 at the moment. We are planning to move VS2010 soon.

Can we use VS2010 with CC.net 1.5.0 ? What is the recommanded version for VS2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to move to VS2010, you can use the Continuous Integration Feature of TFS 2010.. I assume you have TFS 2010.. CI is one of its built in features. When you create a new build, one of the tabs in the "wizard" is dedicated to setting when you want the build to run, and you can set it to run everytime something is checked in (which is a CI build), or you can set it to save up its changes and run no more frequently than a specified period of time.

You don't need CC.Net or NAnt. TFS actually auto creates an MSBuild file which you can then extend if you want to do extra things with your build (like build MSIs, or deploy the built files to other locations, etc etc).

On the otherhand if you are perticular about CC.NET, I don't see any challenge with CC.net 1.5.0. Please do not use the beta builds of CC.NET as we had issues with the dashboard and custom actions in past.

Comment: Is CC.net 1.6 a beta version?   http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/files/CruiseControl.NET%20Releases/CruiseControl.NET%201.6/

Comment: No- It shows 1.6 also as a release version.. I would suggest you make sure your build script is compatible with the current version by running the test on a sample project. We have done couple of things like versioning, IIS VD generation etc in post build actions in past and found that new CC.NET version was failing where the older was working fine.. its all about time and resources..

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a version of Visual Studio 2010 that can build your code. I have used CruiseControl.NET to build .NET 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0 code (Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010). It all works.

Basically CruiseControl.NET starts other processes (like msbuild) and the version of  CruiseControl.NET do not affect what programs you can run to do your build.

If you are using Team Foundation Server in CruiseControl.NET then some versions of CruiseControl.NET needs specific versions of Team Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

We have a CruiseControl.NET server running, with the newest released version (1.6.7981.1). It has projects which build using MSBuild of VS 2005, VS 2008 and VS 2010 with no problems.